# How to group by, count and return tuples using Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

If I have a table like this:

```
ID      VALUE  
---------------
1       a      
1       a      
2       a      
2       a      
2       a      
3       a      
7       a
```

In spark, I load this up from a CSV into a spark data frame like:

```
myDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("filepath/to/my/csv")
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
ID      COUNT  
---------------
1       2      
2       3      
3       1      
7       1
```

And this would be outputted as a CSV so I need a tuple of `(id, count)`

So basically, a group by "id" and then count how many of "id" occurred.

I think I can do this using a reduceByKey, but I am wondering what are the efficient or better solutions for this? Is `reduceByKey` the only possibility? I'm also using Python

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) and [Count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count.html)

##### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
1       a      
1       a      
2       a      
2       a      
2       a      
3       a      
7       a
""".split()

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "id   value".split()))
            
n = len(input_values)

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,n,2)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  1|    a|
|  2|    a|
|  2|    a|
|  2|    a|
|  3|    a|
|  7|    a|
+---+-----+
```

##### GroupBy and Count

```
sparkDF.groupBy('id').count().show()

+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  7|    1|
|  3|    1|
|  1|    2|
|  2|    3|
+---+-----+
```